# angularJS $resource with basic authentiction and JSONP

Tags: angularjs, jsonp

I am newbie to angularJS, i am using $resource to access a RestAPI.  is authentication possible in $resource with JSONP in angularJS?

Comment: If your authentication requires a header, you can set it like this. $http.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = ...

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible.

You should configure the headers of your httpRequests to include the `withCredentials` one.

It can be done this way:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {
    // Default with credential to all methods
    $httpProvider.defaults.withCredentials = true;
}]);
```

More on headers, see the [docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24http).